# ECS cluster not properly distributing Tasks across two EC2 instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

I have a ECS Cluster with 5 services. Each service has one task each. I have two EC2 instances. The /etc/ecs/ecs.config file in each EC2 instance has the following entry.

```
ECS_CLUSTER=qa-cluster
ECS_BACKEND_HOST=
```

In the ECS Cluster information page, under the "ECS Instances" tab, I see two container instances. However, only the first Container instance has all "5" tasks running under it. The second container instance has "0" tasks.   For the second EC2 instance, "Agent Connection" is "True" and Status is "ACTIVE". I am unable to understand why ECS is not creating any tasks under the second container.

Comment: Is there a requirement that you balance across EC2 instances? One of the biggest benefits of using a container management system like ECS is that you don't have to worry about this kind of thing.

Comment: I understand that balancing across EC2 instances is taken care by ECS, but I used to see both the EC2s with different services. Now I see only one EC2 with all the services, which I don't understand